# Using typedef with wire in SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, typedef, system-verilog, edaplayground

When using **typedef** to declare a user-defined type, both these forms are accepted by **EDA Playground**:

```
typedef reg[4:0] reg5;
typedef logic[4:0] logic5;
```

However, if doing something similar based on `wire` type, then this format fails:

```
typedef wire[4:0] wire5;
```

I get "Syntax Error".

How can that be explained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is illegal to declare a `typedef` with a `wire` type, according to the IEEE Std 1800-2017.  Refer to section 6.18 *User-defined types*:

```
type_declaration ::=                // from A.2.1.3 
typedef data_type type_identifier { variable_dimension } ;
```

A `wire` is not a `data_type`, whereas `reg` and `logic` are.  A `wire` is a `net_type`.

Answer (score 1):

A `typedef` defines a *datatype* that can be applied to a net or variable object kinds. Things are confusing to maintain backward compatibility with Verilog because of implicit definitions.

When you see

```
logic [4:0] v;
```

This is implicitly a variable declaration `a` with an explicit 5-bit 4-state packed array datatype.

```
var logic [4:0] v;
```

When you see

```
wire [4:0] w;
```

This is explicitly a net declaration `a` with a 5-bit implicit 4-state packed array datatype.

```
wire logic [4:0] w;
```

You can use a `typedef` for both:

typedef logic [4:0] uint5;

```
var  uint5 v; // var can be implicit
wire uint5 w;
```

Note that module `input` and `inout` ports have `wire` as the implicit object kind. Also `reg` and `logic` are synonyms for 4-state types with `logic` being the preferred keyword. A `reg` is not always associated with a *register*.